# ArgumentsOutOfRangeExeption in a list<T>

Tags: c#, list, exception, random, game-engine

Im getting this exeption thrown when the method is invoked. the list contains exactly 52 objects(number of cards).
Any suggestions what may cause it? maybe the Add and RemoveAt Methods? Or maybe the Random?
The compiler also tell the the problem is in deck.Add(temp[j]); line.

```
public void Shuffle()
        {
            List<Card> temp = new List<Card>();
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                for (int j = rand.Next(i, 52); j < 52; j++)
                {
                    temp.Add(deck[j]);
                    deck.RemoveAt(j);
                    deck.Add(temp[j]);
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: this code.. What is the point of that inner loop if you're not going to use it to loop?

Comment: Its just a demo for the shuffle method , nothing special right now.

Comment: I think your real problem is, that you call `deck.RemoveAt(j);` before `deck.Add(temp[j]);`. So you may be trying to delete an entry at e.g. index 42 that's not yet there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's imagine we are on the first run through the loops. First iteration of both the outer and inner loop. `i` is `0`, and `Rand(i, 52)` produces `13`.

So we have:

> i - 0
>       j - 13
>       temp - empty list
>       deck - assume this is a list with 52 elements

Now let's run the three lines of code inside the loop:

```
temp.Add(deck[j]);
```

Get the 13th item of `deck` and add it to `temp`. Ok, done. `temp` now has 1 item.

```
 deck.RemoveAt(j);
```

Remove the 13th item in `deck`. Ok, fine.

```
 deck.Add(temp[j]);
```

Get the 13th item in `temp` and add it to, wait, what?1? `temp` only has 1 item! `Exception`! `Exception`!.

There isn't a need for the `temp` list in the first place. There is a [very good shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) that involves going through the original list of items once (not N times). And you just need one `temp` variable to hold a value while you swap it with another. Like this:

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    Card temp;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.Length; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int j = rand.Next(0, i + 1);
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
   }
}
```

Done.

Comment: Yeah, your shuffle code really works, thanks all. although im gonna stay with mine untill it will work. I dont like copy pasting codes.

Comment: @God Fair enough. If you can describe in words how you envision your approach working, perhaps somebody could help you to get it to work. I know you gave a short description to omikad, but if you could tell us in more detail what _process_ you are trying to use (e.g. why two loops? why is `temp` a list?), we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I still i wanted it to do outerLoop * innerLoop number of shuffles. That why i used the outer loop. and for the temp list<T> i guess that was a bad idea and a temp object is better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shuffle list of items then you can use the following method:

```
    public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> arr, Random rnd)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            var j = rnd.Next(i, arr.Count);

            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

This method will help you shuffle your deck without ArgumentsOutOfRangeExeption

Comment: I will try it eventually if i will not find a solution. but there a method that shuffles the deck with my code idea?? thanks you all.

Comment: @God Your code idea makes no sense and even if it weren't throwing exceptions, it's extremely inefficient. So it's unlikely there's a shuffling method that uses it.

Comment: @God please write your idea by words. Do you want to create some interesting probability distribution? All answers here corresponds to the uniform distribution.

Comment: Shuflle the deck 52 times each time with a random number between 0 - 51

Answer (score 1):

`temp[j]` does not neccessarily exist. You will need to initialize `temp` so it has at least `j`+1 entries or you need to change the line of `temp[j]` to something more fitting.

Comment: I initilized the list so now it exist. Still throws the Exeption. And what could be more fitting in your though?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `rand.Next(i, 52)`, the result could be 52, which would be out of range for your deck and temporary deck.

Also, you need to initialize your `temp` list, as @nvoigt points out. `List` has a constructor that takes an integer for the initial size. You could pass in 52. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx.

You could have also easily debugged this yourself by looking at the value of `j` in your debugger.

Comment: I did all you said(Initilize the list to 52 objects and rand.Next(1,51)) and its still throws that eception..

Comment: @siride: No, the maximum can't be 52 since the second argument of `Next` is the **exclusive** upper bound: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So i get your head i need to initilize it to 51??

Comment: Got ya. but it still Throw the Exeption.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the docs. Looks like there's a better answer anyway.